# Copying the js objects value into the html as string

Tags: javascript, html, string, dom

I want to create html elements using the values of javascript objects which are not global.

if i run the following code, i take the error: "params is not defined". What i want to do is just copying the value as an argument in the html code.

```
if (params.data.allowedOperations.indexOf('Put') != -1) {
   return "<a onclick=\"ahey('PUT',params.data.allowedOperations)\" href=\"#\"> PUT </a>";
}
```

Comment: You can add data attribute like data-allowedOperations and pass the value. And in onclick function use it

Comment: Is this the only way? If so, how?

Comment: No thats not the only way. The one suggested by treeno also works. The above mentioned was an approach I prefer to organize my data attributes. Here is a plunker as well as treeno suggested - http://plnkr.co/edit/cI2y6gv0mcHVgjadlHLm?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
if (params.data.allowedOperations.indexOf('Put') != -1) {
    return "<a onclick=\"ahey('PUT','"+params.data.allowedOperations+"')\" href=\"#\"> PUT </a>";
}
```

Alternatively you could create an anchor node and then add an eventlistener to it or store the operations in a different attribute e.g.:

```
if (params.data.allowedOperations.indexOf('Put') != -1) {
    return "<a onclick=\"ahey('PUT', this.dataset.allowedOperations)\" data-allowed-operations=\""+params.data.allowedOperations+"\" href=\"#\"> PUT </a>";
}
```

Comment: That's it! First solution is already enough Your second solution doesn't fit to my situation but also useful for future works!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
return "<a onclick=\"ahey('PUT','" + params.data.allowedOperations + "')\" href=\"#\"> PUT </a>";
```

As params.data.allowedOperations being a string, you need to add single quotes around the quotes. In case of number, these are not required.

Comment: you have a syntax-error, so i didnt get it what you mean